# MultiMap in Scala

Tags: generics, scala

I'm trying to mixin the `MultiMap` trait with a `HashMap` like so:

```
val children:MultiMap[Integer, TreeNode] = 
    new HashMap[Integer, Set[TreeNode]] with MultiMap[Integer, TreeNode]
```

The definition for the `MultiMap` trait is:

```
trait MultiMap[A, B] extends Map[A, Set[B]]
```

Meaning that a `MultiMap` of types `A` & `B` is a `Map` of types `A` & `Set[B]`, or so it seems to me. However, the compiler complains:

```
C:\...\TestTreeDataModel.scala:87: error: illegal inheritance;   template $anon inherits different type instances of trait Map:   scala.collection.mutable.Map[Integer,scala.collection.mutable.Set[package.TreeNode]] and scala.collection.mutable.Map[Integer,Set[package.TreeNode]]  
    new HashMap[Integer, Set[TreeNode]] with MultiMap[Integer, TreeNode]  
    ^ one error found
```

It seems that generics are tripping me up again.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had to import `scala.collection.mutable.Set`. It seems the compiler thought the Set in `HashMap[Integer, Set[TreeNode]]` was `scala.collection.Set`. The Set in the MultiMap def is `scala.collection.`**`mutable`**`.Set`.

Answer (score 12):

That can be annoying, the name overloading in Scala's collections is one of its big weaknesses.

For what it's worth, if you had `scala.collection._` imported, you could probably have written your `HashMap` type as:

```
new HashMap[ Integer, mutable.Set[ TreeNode ] ]
```